# React Native elements that are generated outside the Render function does not catch state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have encountered a strange behavior such that when I generate a view outside the `Render` function, even though it is rendered at the first generation (with the help of `this.forceUpdate`), it is not re-rendered when the state changes. Which means this does not work properly:

```
  generateTestView() {
    let l_generatedView = (
      <View
        ref={ref => {
          this.testAnimatedView = ref;
        }}
        style={styles.viewOutRender}>
        <Text>{'Generated Out of Render - ' + this.state.controlText}</Text>
      </View>
    );
    this.setState({
      generatedView: l_generatedView,
      buttonToShow: 'showChange',
    });
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  changeControlText() {
    this.setState({
      controlText: 'NEW VALUE',
    });
    // this.forceUpdate() also fails here
  }

  render() {
    let l_inRenderView = (
      <View style={styles.viewInRender}>
        <Text>{'Generated Inside Render -  ' + this.state.controlText}</Text>
      </View>
    );
    return (
      <View>
...        {this.state.generatedView ? this.state.generatedView : undefined}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

To cross-check, when I generate a view inside the `Render` function, that view is re-rendered when the state is changed. Which means this works properly as expected:

```
  changeControlText() {
    this.setState({
      controlText: 'NEW VALUE',
    });
  }

  render() {
    let l_inRenderView = (
      <View style={styles.viewInRender}>
        <Text>{'Generated Inside Render -  ' + this.state.controlText}</Text>
      </View>
    );
    return (
      <View>
...
        {l_inRenderView}
...
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Related expo snack that can be tested is [here](https://snack.expo.io/@mehmetkaplan/39a794). When you click the button "Generate View", it generates a new view and shown properly. Then when you click "Change Control Text", even though the view (generated in `Render` function, green background) is re-rendered, the other view (generated outside of `Render` function, yellow background) is not re-rendered.

Please note that, this is a simplified version of a bulk code that I have which is used for animations. Because of some animation related necessities, I need to generate the views outside of the `render` function.

So the question is how I can force React-Native to re-render the elements that are generated outside of `Render` function.

**Edit:** In the actual code there will be hundreds of objects that need to find their locations dynamically and will have discrete animations. That is why regenerating same objects again and again will cause performance problems. That is why I am trying to re-use already generated objects. And that is the reason I am trying to avoid the Render function. Otherwise garbage collector will be in deep trouble.

Comment: Didn't you say it yourself? You have to generate components inside the render function

Comment: As I tried to state in last 2 paragraphs because of some animation related necessities (and bulk number of object generations) I am trying to avoid render function. (Else probably everything will be so slow since Render will generate excessive amount of objects).

Comment: If you need to generate views outside the render() function you are doing something else wrong, render() is the only place where the view gets updated, there is no other option. You can use methods to break the render into little manageable performant bits, this is called composing a view with different components.

Comment: Where are you calling this ` generateTestView()` ? You are not really updating the view outside the render function in your example, when you call `setState` react updates the state and calls the render function.

Comment: @AvinKavish for your prior comment yes, if you have normal amount of objects that is the proper way. But if you need to animate hundreds of objects with dynamic initial locations and dynamic non entangled animations you need to avoid render because you’ll end up with generating lots of objects that are to be passed to garbage collector after consecutive renders. That is why I have to go with the existing objects. And for your last comment, kindly please check the expo snack. That function is called by a TouchableOpacity element.

Comment: Where are you calling generateTextView()? Try calling it in changeControlText right after updating the state

Comment: I understand your requirement. But your text is misleading, you are not generating a view outside the render function, you are passing a view to the render function as part of state.

Comment: @AvinKavish would you please point the exact sentence so that I can change? (I believe header and the content are correct but I may be missing a catch).

Comment: @MaStErNeWbIe , the state will change lots of times that is why they have to be separated.

Comment: How about passing a full object of changes to a final function that takes it as a param and changes the state one time with these changes (say pass them to generateTextView for example)

Comment: Text should be fine, it was a misunderstanding.

Comment: @MaStErNeWbIe In that case I would run into garbage collector case that I mentioned above. In the actual code there will be hundreds of objects that need to find their locations dynamically and will have discrete animations. That is why regenerating same objects again and again will cause performance problems. That is why I am trying to re-use already generated objects. And that is the reason I am trying to avoid the Render function. Otherwise garbage collector will be in deep trouble. (I think it will be better if I add this explanation into the original post).

Comment: Except that is done by the react framework and not you.

Comment: @AvinKavish Yes but lots of ‘’’... = new Array(someBigNumber)’’’ within Render is an invitation to bigger troubles.

Comment: You shouldn't create the array in render, have the array as part of your state and map it to a view in render.

Comment: These are arrays of react-native elements.  The reason is they are animated and then when the animations end the complete state of the application needs to be re-evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

What you have done here is passed this view fragment

```
      <View
        ref={ref => {
          this.testAnimatedView = ref;
        }}
        style={styles.viewOutRender}>
        <Text>{'Generated Out of Render - ' + this.state.controlText}</Text>
      </View>
```

to the render function using the state variable. i.e. `this.state.generatedView`

When you use this syntax, `{this.state.generatedView ? this.state.generatedView : undefined}`, you are simply embedding that view portion into the greater render() function. However, the embedded view itself is of the same structure, there is no difference from the last embedded view passed to it. Except this variable,

- `this.state.controlText`

If you make no changes to this variable, the internal renderer of react sees the view tree as being identical to the previous tree, and the [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) process decides that there are no updates to be made to the view/user interface. It doesn't matter whether the view components are generated in or outside the render function, all that matters is the content returned from the render() function. (into the react framework renderer)

Excerpt from the [forceUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) docs

> React will still only update the DOM if the markup changes.

But yours's hasn't. In order to see a difference,

```
    this.setState({
      controlText: 'NEW VALUE' + this.state.controlText,
    });
```

Set your control text to a different value than the previous one. And since you have added the complexity of having part of your view inside the state variable (for reasons that are beyond my comprehension and against every best practice philosophy), call the method that updates the bit of view in your state again.

```
    this.setState({
      controlText: 'NEW VALUE' + this.state.controlText,
    }, () => generateTestView())
```

by passing the method as a parameter to the setState function which ensures that the method is only called when the state has updated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the thing that I was looking for was `setNativeProps`. Changing the two functions as below solved the problem. I am posting the answer here for anybody who are stuck with similar cases.

```
  generateTestView() {
    let l_generatedView = (
      <View
        ref={ref => {
          this.testAnimatedView = ref;
        }}
        style={styles.viewOutRender}>
        <TextInput editable={false} ref={ref => (this.testTextRef = ref)} value={'Generated Out of Render - ' + this.state.controlText} />
      </View>
    );
    this.setState({
      generatedView: l_generatedView,
      buttonToShow: 'showChange',
    });
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  changeControlText() {
    this.setState(
      {
        controlText: 'NEW VALUE',
      },
      () => {
        this.testTextRef.setNativeProps({text: `Modified in changeControlText - ${this.state.controlText}`});
        this.forceUpdate();
      }
    );
  }
```

---

**Working modified expo snack**:

https://snack.expo.io/@mehmetkaplan/3e5325

**Credits**:

https://medium.com/@payalmaniyar/deep-understanding-of-ref-direct-manipulation-in-react-native-e89726ddb78e

https://hackernoon.com/refs-in-react-all-you-need-to-know-fb9c9e2aeb81